# Pycairo vs. cairocffi vs. Qahirah

Tags: python, graphics, cairo, pycairo

I want to create and rasterize vector graphics in Python. I suspect that [`Pycairo`](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo) or [`cairocffi`](https://github.com/Kozea/cairocffi) (edit: or [`Qahirah`](https://github.com/ldo/qahirah)) are a great choice. (If not, comments are welcome.)

**What are the practical differences between the two?**

Specifically, the [`Pycairo` documentation](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo) says:

> If Pycairo is not what you need, have a look at cairocffi, which is an API compatible package using cffi or Qahirah, which is using ctypes and provides a more "pythonic" API with less focus on matching the cairo C API.

But this raises some questions: In what cases may Pycairo be "not what you need", whereas cairocffi is? In what way are cffi/Qahirah/ctypes better than whatever Pycairo does instead? In what ways is Pycairo not "pythonic"? If cairocffi is better than Pycairo, why is Pycairo more popular, does it have advantages?

**Edit:** [A comma might be missing after "cffi"](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/issues/262) in the quote above. In that case, it's not about "Pycairo vs. cairocffi", but about "Pycairo vs. cairocffi vs. Qahirah".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mimicking the C API closely means that functions take simple arguments.
As an example, the `move_to` function/method looks like this:

```
ctx.move_to(x: float, y: float)→ None
```

If you want to use (x,y) points or vectors in your program,
then at some point you might get annoyed that you need to write,
say, `move_to(P[0], P[1])` instead of just `move_to(P)`.

In Qahirah you write this:

```
p = Vector(x, y)
ctx.move_to(p)
```

or perhaps

```
ctx.move_to(Vector(x, y))
```

or even

```
ctx.move_to((x, y))
```

You can think of the C API as a base level on top it is possible to build more convenient API.

As always, it is a trade-off. Using a direct style C API might be faster (but not much).

More information can be found in the README for Qahirah:

```
https://github.com/ldo/qahirah
```

Then again - if you find a Cairo tutorial using C, it might be easier to use the direct style C API.

Try them both and see what you like.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify: Does your answer compare Qahirah to Pycairo? If cairocffi is similar to Pycairo in this regard, then how is it different from Pycairo?

Comment: If you search for "Pycairo" and "Qahirah" on Github you will see that "Pycairo" is used by a lot of projects and Qahirah only by a few. (This could be because Qahirah is newer). So I suggest trying Pycairo first.

Comment: Thanks! How does `cairocffi` compare to `Pycairo`?

Comment: It's a drop-in replacement.

Comment: With what pros and cons? I mean, why did people do the work of making this drop-in replacement?